# Empty uri in rest response

Tags: rest, jaxb, restlet, nexus

I am developing a plugin for nexus oss .My app creates a rest call response(to a request from server) . But when the server receives it , it throws error as follows

```
 javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:
 unexpected element (uri:"", local:"com.collabnet.teamforge.ia.types.GetConfigurationParametersResponse"). 
Expected elements are 
\lt{http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp}CreateProjectConfigurationRequest\gt,
\lt{http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp}GetConfigurationParametersRequest\gt,
\lt{http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp}GetConfigurationParametersResponse\gt,
\lt{http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp}GetPageComponentParametersRequest>
```

I guess the reason behind this exception is that the response doesn't match with the expected because the uri ( this is just my guess , if it's wrong please correct me),that is the namespace in response is not set .

snip of the Code in my plugin is as follows

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "configurationParameter"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetConfigurationParametersResponse", namespace = "http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp")
public class GetConfigurationParametersResponse
    extends BaseResponse
{
```

Why is name space not picked up while creating response ?

Even correct me if the real reason for the exception is not the empty uri. If so what is the real reason behind this exception ?
Please help .

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message the XML document being passed to JAXB is.  It appears as though this XML is being created by something other than JAXB (I suspect XStream).

```xml
<com.collabnet.teamforge.ia.types.GetConfigurationParametersResponse>
    ...
</com.collabnet.teamforge.ia.types.GetConfigurationParametersResponse>
```

Your JAXB mappings are expecting an XML document like the following:

```xml
<GetConfigurationParametersResponse xmlns="http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp">
    ...
</GetConfigurationParametersResponse>
```

---

If you need to interact with the following XML:

```xml
<com.collabnet.teamforge.ia.types.GetConfigurationParametersResponse>
    ...
</com.collabnet.teamforge.ia.types.GetConfigurationParametersResponse>
```

Then you can change your mapping to be:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "configurationParameter"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "com.collabnet.teamforge.ia.types.GetConfigurationParametersResponse")
public class GetConfigurationParametersResponse
    extends BaseResponse
{
```

Comment: Thanks for responding .Yes exactly . I am getting it in the form that you suggested . What should I do to get the expected form . I am using nexus oss app http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/ . So that must be using xstream . So is there no way to give xml in the expected form even though the app uses xstream ?

Comment: Yes I did a search for knowing if xstream is used in the nexus oss app  https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-oss/search?q=xstream&ref=cmdform . Yes as you suggested they are using xstream. What can I do to give the expected form .

Comment: The nexus plugin which is supposedly taking care of this rest communication is https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-oss/blob/5ac6c0e9b5725e9a07fff0f847efed71bd930952/plugins/restlet1x/pom.xml . I don't know how to find if they are using jaxb or xstream .

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam - I have updated my answer with an approach that should help.

Comment: Yes Thanks . I will check this and revert back to you . Thank you very much for spending your precious time .

Comment: Even after doing the change you suggested  the xml response is the same and the error is the same . Please help .

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam - The error is occurring on the server?  Can you share the code on the client that builds the request?

Comment: My server which gives the GetConfigurationParametersResponse call to this nexus app . this nexus app in turn builds response  and sends it  to server. The server now throws error .

Comment: Hi Blaise Doughan , I have mailed you about the latest developments on this problem .Thanks .