# How can I modify generated files ,created using cxf-codegen plugin and then compile?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, cxf

I am using cxf-codegen maven plugin .The first time I did mvn install ,it generated a set of files  , they were placed in target/generated-sources/cxf folder , all generated files where compiled and packed in the resulting jar by maven.

Now I find that for some reason the namespace attribute is not fetched from the package--info.java while the rest response is created . so my server flings an error saying

```
 javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:
 unexpected element (uri:"", local:"com.collabnet.teamforge.ia.types.GetConfigurationParametersResponse"). 
Expected elements are 
\lt{http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp}CreateProjectConfigurationRequest\gt,
\lt{http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp}GetConfigurationParametersRequest\gt,
\lt{http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp}GetConfigurationParametersResponse\gt,
\lt{http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp}GetPageComponentParametersRequest>
```

So what I have planned to do is , set the namespace attribute in the generated file (GetConfigurationParametersResponse.java) as

@XmlRootElement(name = "GetConfigurationParametersResponse" , namespace = "http://...")

. At present I did the change and did maven install , but nothing seems to happen . That is the change in generated files are ignored by maven install .It is not compiled.

SO my question is

How to make this change I made in generated files to get reflected and get compiled during maven install ?

Comment: are your changes to the generated files getting overwritten when you do maven install?

Comment: No . I just did a maven install and got the jar . To see if the change is reflected I used a online java decompiler http://www.showmycode.com/ . There I found only the old code was there .

Comment: Not only this, I tested this one . The server again flung the same error, meaning the changes did not get reflected .

Comment: To know why the uri is not set I raised another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961790/restlet-seems-to-ignore-pakage-info-java . Now for the time being I am bypassing that problem by setting the namespace in each generated file manually .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the "-xjc-npa" flag to the wsdl2java, it SHOULD fill in all the namespace attributes for you and not generate the package-info.java stuff.   That MAY fix the issue if it really is the issue.   That said, if it still generates namespace="" attributes, that likely means the schema in the wsdl is wrong and doesn't have the elementFormDefault="qualified" attribute in it.

Comment: should I give it as <extraarg>-xjc-npa</extraarg> ? in pom

Comment: Ya I used the above and the namespace got generated as attribute in the generated files . Thanks . +1

Comment: But still the uri"" is empty . I am new to this domain . Can you use your expertise and please help me by solving  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961790/restlet-seems-to-ignore-pakage-info-java?lq=1

Comment: I don't know why uri is empty . Is the empty uri really the issue ? please help .